# How to trigger pull-to-refresh and show its loading animation by java code?

Tags: android, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

I have a fragment using [`pull-to-refresh`](https://github.com/naver/android-pull-to-refresh) to refresh my listview, I know when user pull by hand, `OnRefreshListener` triggered, But i want this:

When users open this fragment, they don't have to pull by hand, fragment itself pull to refresh and show loading animation. Please tell me what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: `PullRefreshListView.setRefreshing(true);`

Comment: @Emmanuel I tried, it did refresh, but it only refreshed, I didn't see the **loading animation**, any solution?

Answer (score 4):

It might be a bit late but for reference i had the same issue and this is how i solved it:

When you call:

```
mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

It wont trigger the circle to animate automatically. To show the loading circle you need to use a **runnable**, this  adds a delay in the UI thread so that it shows the circle animation inside the ui thread. You do this by using the below code in place of the above:

```
mPullToRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
         mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
      }
 });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked perfectly! This answer should be accepted.
Anyway, just to complete, the code above will only "run" the animation, to actually trigger both the animation and the actual refreshing code it's necessary to call the refresh listener inside the runnable.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

try using `youPullToRefreshList.setRefreshing()`

Comment: I tried, it did refresh, but it only refreshed, I didn't see the **loading animation**, any solution?

Comment: when you finish loading data for your list, you must call `youPullToRefreshList.onRefreshComplete();`